# PHP Sockets scripts times out after 3 hours

Tags: php, sockets, timeout

I'm running a PHP script that listens for data packets being sent on a socket.
This version is pretty crude and operates in a continual loop by using the following code:

```
set_time_limit(0);
while(TRUE) 
{
   //read port and do something
}
```

This is working fine, but I've noticed we have to restart the script automatically every three hours.

The set_time_limit(0) should allow the script to run indefinitely - is there a overall PHP setting that means scripts will auto-terminate after a 3 hours?

Comment: Do you run the script through a webserver or command line?

Comment: Track the memory usage of this script... could be that you're hitting the memory cap.

Comment: I've added rudimentary error reporting and I'll keep an eye on the memory usage - running from command line.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no such setting in PHP. What could be the problem is a temporary loss of connection.

As to 3hours... Could it be that your process is creating a small memory leak, which forces the server to terminate the process about every 3 hours? I've had this happen to me in the past.

In regards to @Salman's comment, the difference is that the command line doesn't have various directives enabled by default, most importantly - set_time_limit(0). Meaning, command line scripts can run indeffinitely by default.

Are there any more details to work with?

Comment: Thanks for this, I think you're correct about the memory leak. Thanks for letting me know about the set_time_limit(0), I am running from the command line, but was trying to eliminate all factors.
I'm doing some testing today and will get back to you.

Comment: Think I've solved the problem - the scripts CPU usage was steadily increasing. I've added a usleep(500); to the loop and this has stopped the CPU jump. Will let you know in a few hours.

Answer (score 0):

According to this 9 year old post:
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=29560 
There is a bug in sockets that causes it to leak memory.
Used stream_socket_server instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
$start_time_increment =  strtotime("7.00am");
$end_time_increment =  strtotime("10.00pm");

for ($date = $start_time_increment; $date <=$end_time_increment; $date = strtotime("+3 hours",$date)) **{**
    echo date(" h:i:a",$date)."<br />";
}
```